# Euro currency symbol creeping into parsed excel output

Tags: excel, perl, xml-parsing

I'm using [Spreadsheet::BasicRead](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::BasicRead) to extract data from a spreadsheet generated by a Quickbooks online report. Some cells have what look to be a currency format with a leading dollar sign. However, after extracting the data, data from those cells look like this: `'20.00  €'`.

I could just strip out the symbol, but would like to know why this is happening. I inspected the xml inside the xlsx file and see the euro symbol in there (even though in the spreadsheet it is displayed as a dollar sign):

```
styles.xml:<styleSheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><numFmts count="2"><numFmt numFmtId="165" formatCode="#,##0.00\ _€"/><numFmt numFmtId="166" formatCode="&quot;$&quot;* #,##0.00\ _€"/></numFmts>
```

Is there a solution? Maybe I just need a better spreadsheet parser?

Comment: I tracked the problem down to the function in the Spreadsheet::XLSX module: https://metacpan.org/release/Spreadsheet-XLSX/source/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm#L210

Specifically, the foreach loop that handles formats.

Comment: You ask to to know why this is happening, then proceed to answer your own question. (Quickbook said to use a Euro symbol.) You then ask if there's a solution, but you showed that S::BR is doing exactly as told. Finally, you suggest a better spreadsheet parser might work, except you've pointed out that the spreadsheet parser is working correctly. What is it you want from us?

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell, the `_€` add padding to the left hand side of the cell. I have confirmed this by adding several `_€` characters at the end of the custom format in an Excel spreadsheet program. According to MS documentation, the underscore adds in a space equal to the width of the character that follows it.

I'm not sure why Quickbooks chose the euro symbol.

At any rate, this format specifier should get stripped out.